# How to leave disabled buttons disabled after screen rotation?

Tags: android, button, screen-rotation

onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) ?!
Maybe better idea is...

Answer (score 0):

```
Override public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
//disable your button here(First try, i think it will be disabled already, if not you can add disable code here
}
```

Comment: This is far from a complete answer.. maybe tell the user how to config his manifest? and this from android reference: This technique should be considered a last resort when you must avoid restarts due to a configuration change and is not recommended for most applications.